# How to connect multiple device/client with server and how communicate with these connected devices?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, networking, tcplistener

Actually I have a written a code to established a multiple client/device connection with server. My code established a multiple a connection with server and shows me a list of connected clients after When I select a connected device and try to send messages to client it's working fine but When I try to receive a messages from client it's not working.

Here is my Code:

**Below code established a multiple client/devices connection with server**

```
  private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
    
    
                  string Systemip = getlocalip();
                  txtinfo.Text = "Server IP:" + Systemip + Environment.NewLine;
                  var portno = Int32.Parse("8010");
    
                  String a = "";
    
                  IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Systemip);
                  server = new TcpListener(ip, portno);
                  server.Start();
    
                 //here environment.newline means, display msg to next line.
                  txtinfo.AppendText("Server started waiting for client.............." + Environment.NewLine);
              counter = 0;
              f = new Form1();
              Thread newone = new Thread(loop);
              newone.Start();
    
    
          }
          public delegate void messageone();
          public void mess()
          {
    
              richtxtbddata.AppendText(counter + "clien connected" + Environment.NewLine);
              richtxtbddata.AppendText("The client is from IP address: " + ((IPEndPoint)socketforclient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
          //    iplist.Items.Add(((IPEndPoint)socketforclient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
              listBox1.Items.Add(counter);         //add this (((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()); on the place of counter
          }
    
          public void loop(object obj)
          {
              connectobj = new List<Multipleconnect>();
    
              while (true)
              {
                  counter++;
    
                  socketforclient = server.AcceptSocket();
                 // ns = new NetworkStream(socketforclient);
                  connectobj.Add(new Multipleconnect
                  {
                      objectno = counter,
                      Skt = socketforclient,
                      nstream = new NetworkStream(socketforclient),
                      ip = ((IPEndPoint)socketforclient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()
                  });
    
                  //Box.AppendText(counter + "Client connected");
                  richtxtbddata.Invoke(new messageone(mess));
                  Thread UserThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => f.User(socketforclient)));
                  UserThread.Start();
    
              }
          }
          public void User(Socket client)
          {
              while (true)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
                      int size = client.Receive(msg);
                      client.Send(msg, 0, size, SocketFlags.None);
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      txtinfo.Text = "Divice Disconnected";
                  }
    
              }
    
          }
```

**Below code is for sending and receiving a messages but In this code messages sent client/device successfully but this code is not receive a messages from client/devices.**

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       isNew = true;

           if (servermsg.Text != "") {

               ns = new NetworkStream(socketforclient);
               StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);

               writer.WriteLine(servermsg.Text + Environment.NewLine);
               txtinfo.AppendText("Server:" + servermsg.Text + Environment.NewLine);
               writer.Flush();
               writer.Close();
           }


           ns = new NetworkStream(socketforclient);
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
           string myCompleteMessage = string.Empty;

           if (ns.DataAvailable)
           {
               myReadBuffer = new byte[2048];
               datafinal = new double[1];

               myCompleteMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, readbytes);

           }

           //runn();



           if (myCompleteMessage != "")
           {
              txtinfo.AppendText("Client:" + myCompleteMessage + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
           }

       }
```

**Below is my complete code for you to check the issue you can copy paste this code.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// single connection in working condition with old code.....
/// </summary>

namespace TCPSERVER
{
  
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Multipleconnect> connectobj;

        Form1 f;
        int counter = 0;
        NetworkStream ns;
        int i = 0;
        Socket socketforclient;
        TcpListener server;
        byte[] myReadBuffer;
        int readbytes;
        int p = 0;
        int y;
        double[] datafinal;
        double[] yy;
        List<double> xx;
        string stop = "";
        Multipleconnect mulcon = new Multipleconnect();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //txtserverip.Text = getlocalip();
         
            Featuresduringrun();
         //   Connnection();
        }

        private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            
                string Systemip = getlocalip();
                txtinfo.Text = "Server IP:" + Systemip + Environment.NewLine;
                var portno = Int32.Parse("8010");
             
                String a = "";

                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Systemip);
                server = new TcpListener(ip, portno);
                server.Start();

               //here environment.newline means, display msg to next line.
                txtinfo.AppendText("Server started waiting for client.............." + Environment.NewLine);
            counter = 0;
            f = new Form1();
            Thread newone = new Thread(loop);
            newone.Start();

 
        }
        public delegate void messageone();
        public void mess()
        {

            richtxtbddata.AppendText(counter + "clien connected" + Environment.NewLine);
            richtxtbddata.AppendText("The client is from IP address: " + ((IPEndPoint)socketforclient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        //    iplist.Items.Add(((IPEndPoint)socketforclient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
            listBox1.Items.Add(counter);         //add this (((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()); on the place of counter
        }

        public void loop(object obj)
        {
            connectobj = new List<Multipleconnect>();

            while (true)
            {
                counter++;

                socketforclient = server.AcceptSocket();
               // ns = new NetworkStream(socketforclient);
                connectobj.Add(new Multipleconnect
                {
                    objectno = counter,
                    Skt = socketforclient,
                    nstream = new NetworkStream(socketforclient),
                    ip = ((IPEndPoint)socketforclient.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()
                });

                //Box.AppendText(counter + "Client connected");
                richtxtbddata.Invoke(new messageone(mess));
                Thread UserThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => f.User(socketforclient)));
                UserThread.Start();

            }
        }
        public void User(Socket client)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
                    int size = client.Receive(msg);
                    client.Send(msg, 0, size, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    txtinfo.Text = "Divice Disconnected";
                }

            }




        }




        public static string getlocalip()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach(var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "not found any ip";
        }
 
        private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string aa = listBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
            if (aa == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selexct a item");

            }
     

            
            if (servermsg.Text != "") {
               
                ns = new NetworkStream(socketforclient);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
               
                writer.WriteLine(servermsg.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                txtinfo.AppendText("Server:" + servermsg.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
      

            ns = new NetworkStream(socketforclient);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
            string myCompleteMessage = string.Empty;

            if (ns.DataAvailable)
            {
            myReadBuffer = new byte[2062];
            int rreadbytes = ns.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            string Client2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, rreadbytes);
            myCompleteMessage = Client2;

            }

          
            if (myCompleteMessage != "")
            {
               txtinfo.AppendText("Client:" + myCompleteMessage + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }










   
  

      
  
  

 
         
   
      
        private Form activeform = null;

     
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string aa = listBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
            if (aa == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selexct a item");

            }
            ////  int endindex = aa.Length - 1;
            //// int b = aa.IndexOf("}");
            ////aa = aa.Substring(15, 13);

            foreach (var ob in connectobj)
            {
                if (ob.objectno.ToString() == aa)     //write ob.ip on the place of ob.objectno
                {
                    socketforclient = ob.Skt;
                    MessageBox.Show("yes");
                }
            }
        }

  
    }
}
```

**Below code comes another class which is used to store the multiple client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TCPSERVER
{
    class Multipleconnect
    {
        public int objectno;
        public Socket Skt;
        public string ip;
        public NetworkStream nstream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to communicate between clients directly? As usual, the server can see all messages from the client. You can provide a  completed code for it so that we can test it.

Comment: I want to connect multiple client/device with my server and server communicate with the selected device  from the list of connected device, my progress is my server send the messages to the selected device from the list of connected device but my server is not receiving any message from any connected client .

Comment: Based on my test, I find a problem. As usual, we will divide into two parts when we deal with socket problem. One is Server, and One is Client. I suggest that you don't put them in the same program.

Comment: I have wireless device which act like a client so can't write a code for my client, this device directly communicate with the server using TCP protocols via WIFI. This device reply the server based on the server command which is send to the device. Server send the command to device in ASCII character like BL ? it mean server asking a question to device what is a battery level then device reply to server like BL = 84. My code is working when i write this code for only device i mean my server send and received a messages from device.

Comment: But the problem is when i write a code for server to communicate multiple device at that time my code is not working fine server send a command to device but not received any reply from device(but device always send a reply of every server command). My server communicate with selected device/client  from the list of connected device and then send the command to the device which already selected by me from the list of connected device at that time my server send the command to device but my server does not  receive any message from device.